# Upper limit on "unconstrained" histogram parts

Tags: probability, histogram

I am wondering if there is a way to estimate upper limits on a histogram:

I have an observation with 200 measurements, those scatter around some value  with some variance. For context, x is the light intensity of a light source.

If I choose some reasonable bin width, with a bin range spanning from the minimum and maximum x measured. Is it correct that the first unpopulated bin to either side must have a probability of P(x) < 1/200?

I assume that I can measure *all* events, without running into some kind of detection threshold. A detection threshold could be, for instance, some kind of stray light, that is captured by the measurement apparatus and outshines the actual source.

The question is relevant in the context of trying to discriminate different model probability distribution functions against each other: The absence of fainter than $x_{min}$ measurements implies that the source is almost never fainter than $x_{min}$. In consequence, models that predict such values with significant probability could be disfavoured.

Can one estimate the "uncertainty" on such an upper limit?

How does that depend on the bin width (let's say I use unequal bin widths?)

Is there something that could save me in the case when x is not iid? I know that x is red-noise-ish, with some crude idea of the correlation time/length.

I suspect that I am missing the terminology of how such a way of estimating probabilities is called, (citable) reading links are much appreciated!

Comment: You have 200 measurements: it is conventional to extend the limits of the histogram axis from the smallest to the largest in order to comprise them all.  In what sense, then, are you asking to "estimate" the limits?  What do you mean by "detection threshold" and how is this related to your question?

Comment: I've edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.